# Return all instances of a class that meet a criterion

Tags: python

I'm completely new to Python so I may not be asking this in the right way and I have tried to find an answer (unsuccessfully, obviously).

I am trying to set up a class and then to find all instances of the class that meet a certain criterion. I don't know if a class is the right way to go about this so open to all advice (even if it takes me away from classes).

For a simple example (see code below) if I wanted to find all Employee's who are over 30 would the right approach be to make a class method? In reality you'd have DOB rather than age but for simplicity I've gone with age. I'd also want some sort of variable so that I could change 30 to let's say 50.

```py
class Employee:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

e1 = Employee("John", 36)
e2 = Employee("Sally", 21)
e3 = Employee("Jamie", 53)
```

What is the "right" way or efficient way to achieve this? For this example above for ages above 30 I'd want the e1 and e3 instances. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would typically have your instances in some sort of collection like a list rather than individual variables. You could then filter your list or use a list comprehension to get the elements in the list you want. Here's an example with a list comprehension:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

employees = [
    Employee("John", 36),
    Employee("Sally", 21),
    Employee("Jamie", 53)
]

over_thirty = [e for e in employees if e.age > 30]

for e in over_thirty:
    print(e.name)
```

**prints:**

```
John
Jamie
```

You can avoid the extra list `over_thirty` and iterate directly over the filter results for the same result:

```
for e in filter(lambda e: e.age > 30, employees):
    print(e.name)
```

Comment: An alternative is to have the instances join themselves to some collection at creation time, or have Python enumerate all objects in the class namespace. I would not recommend either here, so just mentioning them for completeness.

Comment: Thank you! This makes perfect sense but I was missing the vital point of having the instances in a collection. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Or also modify the class:

```
class Employee:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.age_over_30 = self.age > 30

l = [Employee("John", 36), Employee("Sally", 21), Employee("Jamie", 53)]
print([i.name for i in l if i.age_over_30])
```

Or if you would modify the `age` attribute, make the class:

```
class Employee:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
  @property
  def age_over_30(self):
      return self.age > 30
```

Comment: Would this dynamically update if 30 was instead a variable that changed elsewhere in the program?

Comment: @Cbfed Check my second example